# Python regex multiline

Tags: regex, python-3.x, multiline

I am trying to extract some information from multiline text, but with no luck i am just gettign None
what i am missing, i dont know?

```
content = """
Cisco IOS Software, C880 Software (C880DATA-UNIVERSALK9-M), Version 15.4(2)T1, RELEASE SOFTWARE 
(fc3)

ROM: System Bootstrap, Version 12.4(22r)YB5, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)



Cisco 999 (MPC8300) processor (revision 1.0) with 236544K/25600K bytes of memory.
Processor board ID FTX0000088X






Configuration register is 0x210
"""



print()
match = re.search(r".* Version (?P<OS_Version>\S+), .* Processor board ID (?P<Serial_Number>.* 
Configuration register is (?P<config_register>\S+)$", 
content, flags=re.M) 
print(match)
```

Comment: There is an incomplete group structure for group `Serial_Number`. There is no space before `Processer board ID` and `Configuration register`and you have to enable `re.DOTALL` to make the dot match a newline. https://regex101.com/r/pE2ixV/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's many problem in your regex :

- The flag `re.DOTALL` is missing to make `.` match newlines.
- `\S+` will match the comma after your version, which I don't think you want.
- The capture group `(?P<Serial_Number>` is not closed.
- It's a newline before `Processor board ID` and `Configuration register`, not a space.
- You have a `$` just after the `config_register` group, but there's actually a newline before the end of your text.

Depending on which version you want, you regex would be something like:

```py
match = re.search(
    r".*?Version (?P<OS_Version>[\w().]+).*board ID (?P<Serial_Number>\w+).*register is (?P<config_register>\w+)",
    content,
    flags=re.M|re.DOTALL
)
```

or

```py
match = re.search(
    r".*Version (?P<OS_Version>[\w().]+).*board ID (?P<Serial_Number>\w+).*register is (?P<config_register>\w+)",
    content,
    flags=re.M|re.DOTALL
)
```

The difference is that a `?` is added after the `.*` at the start, making it non greedy and retrieving the code after the first occurence of `Version`.